What is a program in R that can complete a pathway analysis for non-model organisms?
I have a whole genome annotation for a non-model organism that was downloaded from the NCBI including a .gff and .gtf file. These files were used along with raw reads of mRNA from 12 different animals from 5 tissues types forming my dataset of  5 .csv files showing genes of significant differential gene expression, that were output by the DESeq2 program in R, each with up to 8,000 genes that showed differential expression between two treatments. I already have heat maps of WGCNA modules, the top 100 genes differentially expressed, scatterplots showing log2fold change vs. base mean, and WGCNA module box plot showing relatedness. However, I am hoping to expand my results to a comprehensive pathway analysis but am so far unsuccessful.
Here is what I have tried based on looking at different forums. The issue I keep running into is that KEGG returns "no genes found" after I merge my datasets and have parsed out the gene IDs. Ideally a dot plot and list of enriched pathways would be the output I need for intepretation. Something like this: (https://www.biostars.org/p/9564959/). Several times the package "org.Hs.eg.db" has been suggested but this would be for Homo sapiens genes in the Ensembl database which my organism is not in since the genome is not publicly available.
Error
> kegg_enrich <- enrichKEGG(gene = merged_data$gene_symbols)
--> No gene can be mapped....
--> Expected input gene ID: 57103,669,54579,83401,8972,51071
--> return NULL...
> 

Source code
# Load necessary packages
install.packages("clusterProfiler")
library(clusterProfiler)
library(GenomicFeatures)
library(rtracklayer)
library(rtracklayer)
library(dplyr)

# Read genome annotation (.gtf) file to extract gene symbols
gtf_file <- "/my/gtf.gtf"
gtf_data <- read.delim(gtf_file, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "\t", comment.char = "#")
gene_symbols <- gtf_data$V9  # Assumes gene symbols are in the 9th column of the .gtf file

print (gene_symbols)

# Esxtract relevant fields
extract_fields <- function(entry) {
  # Split the entry by semicolons
  fields <- strsplit(entry, "; ")[[1]]
  # Initialize variables to store extracted fields
  gene_id <- transcript_id <- product <- exon_number <- NA
  
  # Loop through each field
  for (field in fields) {
    # Extract gene_id
    if (grepl("^gene_id", field)) {
      gene_id <- gsub("^gene_id ", "", field)
    }
    # Extract transcript_id
    if (grepl("^transcript_id", field)) {
      transcript_id <- gsub("^transcript_id ", "", field)
    }
    # Extract product
    if (grepl("^product", field)) {
      product <- gsub("^product ", "", field)
    }
    # Extract exon_number
    if (grepl("^exon_number", field)) {
      exon_number <- gsub("^exon_number ", "", field)
    }
  }
  
  # Returns a list of extracted fields
  return(list(gene_id = gene_id, transcript_id = transcript_id, product = product, exon_number = exon_number))
}

# Apply the function to each entry in gene_symbols
extracted_fields <- lapply(gene_symbols, extract_fields)

# Convert the list to a data frame
extracted_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, extracted_fields)

# Print the resulting data frame
print(extracted_df)


# Read differential expression data
expression_data <- read.csv("significatnt_expression_data.csv")

print (expression_data)

# Extract gene symbols from the Gene.ID column in expression_data
expression_data$gene_symbols <- sub(".*gene-(.*?)\\|.*", "\\1", expression_data$Gene.ID)

# Merge expression data with extracted_df based on common identifiers
merged_data <- merge(expression_data, extracted_df, by.x = "gene_symbols", by.y = "gene_id", all.x = TRUE)

# Remove rows with NA values in transcript_id (optional)
merged_data <- merged_data[complete.cases(merged_data$transcript_id), ]

# Remove duplicate rows
merged_data <- merged_data %>%
  distinct(gene_symbols, Gene.ID, .keep_all = TRUE)


# Print merged data
print(merged_data)


# Perform pathway analysis using gene symbols
# Example: using enrichKEGG function
kegg_enrich <- enrichKEGG(gene = merged_data$gene_symbols)

# Visualize pathway enrichment results
dotplot(kegg_enrich)


Here is a sample (first few lines) print output of for both the .gtf (extracted_df) file I am trying to use and my expression data (expression_data) for one of my tissues
> print(extracted_df)
 gene_id  transcript_id                                                             product exon_number
1   LOC132387011                                                                               <NA>        <NA>
2   LOC132387011 XR_009509744.1                                        uncharacterized LOC132387011        <NA>
3   LOC132387011 XR_009509744.1                                        uncharacterized LOC132387011           1
4   LOC132387011 XR_009509744.1                                        uncharacterized LOC132387011           2
5   LOC132387011 XR_009509744.1                                        uncharacterized LOC132387011           3
6   LOC132387011 XR_009509744.1                                        uncharacterized LOC132387011           4
7   LOC132386044                                                                               <NA>        <NA>
8   LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4        <NA>
9   LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           1
10  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           2
11  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           3
12  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           4
13  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           5
14  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           6
15  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           7
16  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           8
17  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4           9
18  LOC132386044 XR_009509440.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X4          10
19  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5        <NA>
20  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           1
21  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           2
22  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           3
23  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           4
24  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           5
25  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           6
26  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           7
27  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           8
28  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1 aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like, transcript variant X5           9
29  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1             aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like isoform X4           1
30  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1             aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like isoform X4           2
31  LOC132386044 XM_059958552.1             aspartate aminotransferase, cytoplasmic-like isoform X4           3

> print (expression_data)
                           Gene.ID     baseMean log2FoldChange      lfcSE       stat       pvalue         padj gene_symbols
1                 gene-abce1|abce1  2032.804374      0.6583508 0.21998288   2.992737 2.764882e-03 1.124842e-02        abce1
2   gene-LOC132399254|LOC132399254   733.256071      0.5311220 0.20580205   2.580742 9.858823e-03 3.129345e-02 LOC132399254
3   gene-LOC132387019|LOC132387019    52.985548      1.4847338 0.27225424   5.453483 4.939279e-08 1.426663e-06 LOC132387019
4                 gene-pcloa|pcloa    23.667651     -1.1828477 0.45967995  -2.573198 1.007634e-02 3.181822e-02        pcloa
5   gene-LOC132407644|LOC132407644   417.857584     -4.0265314 0.31768433 -12.674630 8.174333e-37 8.232975e-34 LOC132407644
6   gene-LOC132389433|LOC132389433  5800.931885      0.8439122 0.13877729   6.081054 1.193954e-09 5.822725e-08 LOC132389433
7   gene-LOC132394681|LOC132394681  1991.387414     -0.4354921 0.11589129  -3.757764 1.714388e-04 1.198364e-03 LOC132394681
8                 gene-virma|virma  2159.024149     -0.2922582 0.11589893  -2.521664 1.168011e-02 3.577071e-02        virma
9   gene-LOC132385770|LOC132385770   126.273158     -2.0139865 0.53751523  -3.746845 1.790724e-04 1.238339e-03 LOC132385770
10  gene-LOC132381629|LOC132381629   109.069263      1.8838641 0.36869921   5.109488 3.230334e-07 6.852627e-06 LOC132381629
11                gene-rpl24|rpl24 22716.438306     -0.6882273 0.14354568  -4.794482 1.630953e-06 2.605588e-05        rpl24
12  gene-LOC132389641|LOC132389641    59.322800     -1.4041952 0.51110583  -2.747367 6.007589e-03 2.101567e-02 LOC132389641
13  gene-LOC132385242|LOC132385242   318.845742      1.5171200 0.49462313   3.067224 2.160568e-03 9.195217e-03 LOC132385242
14                  gene-copa|copa  5372.065947      0.9295895 0.15814733   5.877997 4.152617e-09 1.749007e-07         copa
15            gene-camkk1a|camkk1a  2000.139631     -0.8874040 0.26238097  -3.382120 7.192862e-04 3.831318e-03      camkk1a
16  gene-LOC132407705|LOC132407705   486.644297     -0.7049372 0.20016913  -3.521708 4.287768e-04 2.522889e-03 LOC132407705
17                gene-cep68|cep68   478.775396      0.4641919 0.13122832   3.537284 4.042644e-04 2.412297e-03        cep68
18                  gene-rcc1|rcc1  1156.839987      0.5767384 0.21588153   2.671551 7.550170e-03 2.525992e-02         rcc1
19  gene-LOC132379315|LOC132379315  2535.334106     -0.6219417 0.16584854  -3.750058 1.767935e-04 1.225441e-03 LOC132379315
20              gene-cep350|cep350  1083.723625      0.7606137 0.21658289   3.511883 4.449444e-04 2.597477e-03       cep350
21  gene-LOC132382495|LOC132382495   678.689844      1.5565065 0.25229261   6.169449 6.852824e-10 3.607856e-08 LOC132382495
22  gene-LOC132391270|LOC132391270   225.854938      1.3964262 0.48009168   2.908666 3.629748e-03 1.400452e-02 LOC132391270
23  gene-LOC132399774|LOC132399774   222.162836      0.5274968 0.18060820   2.920669 3.492805e-03 1.356654e-02 LOC132399774


The problem is, it looks like your data does not actually have any functional annotations (e.g., from KEGG) so there is nothing to evaluate the enrichment with (and against). Given that this is a non-model organism, perhaps annotate the (I presume) transcriptome that you have with eggnog-mapper (or interproscan) to get gene ontology and KEGG and then try again. Should work after that. I must add that this is also off-topic here as this is not really a programming/computer science(s) issue but a bioinformatics one.
